# rails joins to show second table 's columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, join

I under how joins work

```
Category.joins(:posts)
This produces:

SELECT categories.* FROM categories
  INNER JOIN posts ON posts.category_id = categories.id
```

But how do I get columns data from posts table. Is there away to retrieve all columns from both table like

```
SELECT categories.*,posts.* FROM categories
  INNER JOIN posts ON posts.category_id = categories.id
```

Or I only can achieve this by using raw sql ?

Comment: Is there any relationship defined between the two classes?

Answer (score 0):

```
Category.first.includes(:posts)
```

will eager load all the posts for that Category. See the rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Following the document you give, I think the command should be: Category.includes(:posts).find(1)